# create a button to id that showing on hover in <div> (css)

Tags: html, css

I want to create a button like [README.md (GitHub)](https://github.com/github/docs#github-docs-), when hover on # headline it will show a button link to the that id, [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE9ek.png).

I tried with html:

```
<div id="headline"><a href="#headline" class="to">#</a> HEADLINE</div>
```

css:

```
a.to {
   display: none;
}

#headline:hover + a.to {
   display: block;
}
```

but it's not work

Comment: In your HTML change `<div id="#headline">` to `<div id="headline">` and in your CSS change `#headline:hover + a.to` selector to `#headline:hover a.to`.

Comment: @AmirrezaNoori thanks, it's work and my bad when put id="#" to code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how it's done. You were close, but the `+` combinator only works with adjacent elements. Since the `a` tag is a descendant of the `div`, there would be no need for a combinator.

```css
.to{
  visibility: hidden;
}

#headline:hover .to{
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="headline"><a href="#headline" class="to">#</a> HEADLINE</div>
```

One more thing, to scroll within the DOM, the `href` attribute would have a `#` followed by the `id` of the target element. So to scroll to the div of id "headline", the `href` attribute's value would be `#headline`.

Comment: wait, can I use the `display: none` instead of `visibility: hidden; ` ?

Comment: `display: none;` will basically remove the element and there won't be white space. So when you hover, the `HEADLINE` text will move right and the `#` will appear.

Comment: `visibility: hidden;` just makes it hidden while still occupying space. Looking at the link you provided, `visibility: hidden;` is the way to go.